# Did some Nazis meet in a “gay” bar?

Tags: history, nazi-germany, lgbt

It is an assertion made by the German Journalist, Heinz Hohne in "The Order of the Death's Head". The assertion was popularized by the fraudulent anti-gay book, "pink swatiska". Hohne's book was originally published in German in 1966, translated into English in 1969.

> He used the SA for ends other than the purely political. SA contact men kept their Chief of Staff supplied with suitable partners and at the first sign of infidelity on the part of a Röhm favourite, he would be bludgeoned down by one of the SA mobile squads. The head pimp was a shop assistant named Peter Granninger, who had been one of Röhm's partners since 1928 and was now given cover in the SA Intelligence Section. For a monthly salary of 200 marks he kept Röhm supplied with new friends, his main hunting ground being Gisela High School Munich; from this school he recruited no fewer than eleven boys, whom he first tried out and then took to Röhm. Meanwhile some of Röhm's more dubious friends had occupied senior SA positions left vacant as a result of the Stennes revolt.
>
> The general meeting-point for the Granninger circle and the SA homosexuals was Röhm's reserved table in the Bratwurstglöckl, Munich. The proprietor, Karl Zehnter, was a homosexual himself whom Granninger had "assisted" at his home. Another homosexual and long-standing habitué of Röhm's table was the new Berlin Commander, Edmund Heines; he had even been ex- pelled from the SA in 1927 for homosexual practices. Karl Ernst, the new SA Chief of Staff, Berlin, had been a partner of Captain Rohrbein, ex-Frontbann, who had also frequently been seen with Röhm in Berlin homosexual dives such as the Kleist-Kasino and Silhouette. This ring of perverted SA commanders seemed unbreakable.

[image: This is a photo of the passage about Ernst Roehm, head of the Sturmabteilung and homosexual]

Comment: Which Nazi, when?

Comment: The NSDAP. Between the 5 January 1919 and February 24 1920, it was named DAP (German Workers' Party).

Comment: Heinz Höhne, the German Wikipedia writes, "was criticized by several historians for blindly taking accounts of leading members of the SS at face value". The SS was in rivalry to Röhm's SA.

Comment: @ jjack, Even if the assumption that Heinz Höhne has been criticized by "several historians" is true, does not imply that this assertion is false.

Answer (score 1):

According to the 1944 [Der Fuehrer; Hitler's Rise to Power](https://archive.org/details/derfuehrerhitlersrisetopower/page/n307/mode/2up?q=Bratwurst) by Konrad Heiden:

> Edmund Heines, a choice example of the armed bohemian and political murderer, was the leader of these malcontents in Munich; and, what really made him dangerous, led them in the name of Rohm, who stood aside. Heines was a born ruffian, tall and broad as a barn door, yet as agile as a greyhound; his mighty form was graced by a repulsively girlish face. He would sit with Rohm and other friends in the Bratwurstglöckl, a tavern in the inner city; the host, a certain Zentner, also an S.A. man, was one of the group. They accused Hitler of letting the S.A. go to ruin, not training it in sufficiently military style, giving the soldiers in it unworthy jobs to do. With a heavy heart, Hitler had to intervene — with a heavy heart, because he regretted the loss of a single man; but his personal authority came first. At the end of May, 1927, he called the Munich SA. together in the ‘Hirschbräu-Keller’ beer hall; the public was strictly excluded. Hitler shouted at the crushed assemblage: ‘The clique from the Bratwurstglöckl are all fairies: Heines, Rohm, Zentner, and the rest. Am I expected to take accusations from such people!’
>
> A serious matter, worse than a scandal. The perversion was widespread in the secret murderers’ army of the post-war period, and its devotees denied that it was a perversion. They were proud, regarded themselves as ‘different from the others,’ meaning better. They boasted about their superiority in more or less the same terms which Plato had coined in his *Banquet*: They [the homosexuals] are the best among the boys and young men because they are the most valiant of them. This is strikingly demonstrated by the fact that, after growing up, they — and they alone — are fit for ruling the state.
>
> Rohm said that the misfortune of the present age was domination by women; he praised the epochs that had been dominated by figures like Alexander the Great, Caesar, Charles XII of Sweden, Prince Eugene of Savoy, and Frederick the Great —five great warriors and five homosexuals. Alfred Bäumler, the National Socialist philosopher, whom his comrades in 1933 at once made a professor at the University of Berlin, wrote a whole Book about the ‘heroic young man’: ‘Everywhere the relation between man and man is degenerating,' he lamented . . . ‘there is no place where man Stands beside man, where men come together, the young with the young or the young with their elders, for no other purpose than because it must be so . . . The modern world is a world without friendship . . With the pervert’s arrogance, he went on: ‘The contest for a woman has the peculiarity that both contestants are always defeated, for the victor like the vanquished loses his time. Weak natures . . . are ruined in erotic relationships . . . ’ And then he gave expression to the idea whereon this whole group based their special pride: ‘The friendship relation has a connection with the state, the erotic relation has not . . . Because the German is essentially a warlike nature, because he is a man, because he is born for friendship — democracy, which, in its ultimate consequence, leads to the right of women to judge over men, can never thrive in Germany.’
>
> Here we intend no moral judgment. Yet assuredly the pressure of public censure has distorted more characters, weakened more moral resistance, created more dishonesty toward oneself and others among modern homosexuals than among other people. Lieutenant Rossbach’s troop, roaring, brawling, carousing, smashing windows, shedding blood, and nevertheless seeking the light of freedom, was especially proud to be ‘different from the others.’ Heines had belonged to it before joining Hitler; then Rossbach and Heines had formed a center with Rohm; it led the S.A. while Hitler was under arrest. According to his own indications, Rohm was perverted by the other two. In 1924, his suitcase and papers were stolen from him in the lowest Berlin surroundings, and thus his private life became known to the police. After his break with Hitler, he was destitute; he peddled books, and for a long time lived as a guest of wealthy homosexual friends. In Berlin for a time he frequented the homosexual dregs; he admitted that he had moved in circles where the good citizen blushes and shudders.’